# Can JPQL named parameters be used in more than 1 position?

Tags: jpa, jpql

For example, should I be able to do the following:

```
Query deleteQuery = entityManager.createQuery("delete from LogEntry log "
    + "where log.year < :year "
    + "or (log.year = :year and log.month < :month) "
    + "or (log.year = :year and log.month = :month and log.dayOfMonth <= :dayOfMonth");
deleteQuery.setParameter("year", year);
deleteQuery.setParameter("month", month);
deleteQuery.setParameter("dayOfMonth", dayOfMonth);
int deleteCount = deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Of do I have to define 6 separate named parameters?  The references and javadoc don't explicitly address this case.  I'm trying it in my environment (Glassfish / Eclipselink), but I want whatever final solution I come up with to be portable across JPA implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec does mention that "*the same named parameter can be used more than once in the query string.*"

See section *4.6.4.2 Named Parameters* of the [JPA 2.0 spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html).

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  It seems most of the summaries I found by Googling leave off that one critical sentence. Thanks - no I have a copy of the spec. :)